# IR vision application

Tags: infrared, camera

I'm trying to make an IR visible object tracking device.

Is there any way to convert visible machine vision camera to an IR vision camera

datasheet link:

https://wiki.dfrobot.com/HUSKYLENS_V1.0_SKU_SEN0305_SEN0336

Comment: Did you try if it works with IR light? Or maybe it has a removable IR filter?

Comment: Most camera sensors can see a small part of the IR spectrum (the part closest to the visible spectrum), but just have filters that block it. Changing the filter will make the camera detect IR. However, whether that is useful for you or not depends on what kind of IR you want to detect. Thermal cameras for instance use a part of the spectrum much further from visible light, and that won’t be detected by a regular camera, you’ll need a specific FIR sensor for that.

Comment: Where's the link to the camera datasheet? [Edit] it into the question. (Don't bury it in the comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Your Husky module seems to use an OV2640 camera.  That's the same camera the ESP32 Cam uses.

[This person](https://marksbench.com/electronics/removing-ir-filter-from-esp32-cam/) took the OV2640 from an ESP32 Cam apart and removed the IR filter.

Removing the IR filter will change the way the camera sees color, and you'll need to adjust the focus so that the IR image is sharp rather than the color image.

A summary of the process:

1. Cut through the glue that holds the lens.  The lens is screwed into the tube above the image sensor.  The glue is just there to keep the lens from unscrewing and changing the focus.
2. Remove the lens.
3. Remove the retaining ring that holds the IR filter in place.
4. Remove the IR filter.  Be **careful.** The IR filter lies right on the image sensor.  A mistake here can damage the sensor.
5. Clean any dust or hair or crumbs from the IR filter off of the sensor - **carefully.**
6. Reinstall the lens.
7. Adjust the focus.  Use IR light, and turn off the regular lighting.  Run the lens in or out until the focus is good.  Use a spot of glue to fixate the lens.

---

If you do all of that, you should end up with a functional camera that can see IR.

I can't begin to guess what the video processing algorithms in the Husky module will make of the distorted color video or IR video.  It may work perfectly or the software may throw a fit.

Worst case, there are lenses and IR filters that you can buy and screw into the lens mount of the OV2640. You could install a new IR filter if the Huskey software doesn't like IR.

Answer (score 1):

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4L87yU3Xyw) a man used a camera with a switching IR filtering lens to show that you can filter visible light yourself with a burned picture film or some other tools.

In the case you can't simply toggle off the camera's IR filter, you might still have a lot of work removing it, but with this technique (I didn't test) you could theoretically make a visible light filter, letting in only IR, so you could try strategy combinations. The man in the video also talks about polarized filters 90 degree shifted, but says they also block part of the IR. In the end he talks about a blue + a red light filters.

If you get the filter of your desire, just firm it in front of the camera and be careful not to scratch it, so only the IR you want could pass through. If the cathed IR is not enough, you can also use IR LEDs to "invisibly" illuminate stuff, even though they are weak LEDs, but in that case natural IR might get less distinct. In any case, check out if you really need to remove the IR filter from your camera, I don't know if it filters 100% of the IR. Maybe you could damage just it?

Comment: At the end I meant maybe you could scratch off or something, only the IR filter, but I've no idea if that's possible, it was just a thought.